# jquery redirect after displaying six slider images

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Hi i am following [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-build-a-simple-content-slider-jquery-plugin/)

for building a jquery slider, What i need is to redirect to another web page after displaying six slides currently it is repeating slides.

some code

```
$('ul').jwSlider({
    speed : 2500,
    pause : 3000
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The jwSlider doesn't seem to include any callback for this purpose.
You need to extend the plugin for this special use case.

You can however use a simple workaround that counts the seconds until the redirect should happen:

```
var timeUntilRedirect = numberOfSlides * (speedInMilliseconds + pauseInMilliseconds)

setTimeout(function() {

  // redirect, e.g.:
  window.top.location.href="http://yourdomain.com"

}, timeUntilRedirect);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it removes first element and adds it to the end of the `ul`. So there is no six for it.

You need to add another option `slideShown` and call it in both `slide` and `fade` functions of `jwSlider`

```
...
    var defaults = {
            speed : 1000,
            pause : 2000,
            transition : 'fade',
            slideShown: $.noop
        },
...
        function slide() {
            setInterval(function() {
                // Animate to the left the width of the image/div
                $this.animate({'left' : '-' + $this.parent().width()}, options.speed, function() {
                    // Return the "left" CSS back to 0, and append the first child to the very end of the list.
                    $this
                       .css('left', 0)
                       .children(':first')
                       .appendTo($this); // move it to the end of the line.
                    options.slideShown(); // <------ added call
                })
            }, options.pause);
        } // end slide

        function fade() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $this.children(':first').animate({'opacity' : 0}, options.speed, function() {   
                    $this
                       .children(':first')
                       .css('opacity', 1) // Return opacity back to 1 for next time.
                       .css('zIndex', $this.children(':last').css('zIndex') - 1) // Reduces zIndex by 1 so that it's no longer on top.                  
                       .appendTo($this); // move it to the end of the line.
                    options.slideShown(); // <------ added call
                })
            }, options.pause);
        } // end fade
```

then call

```
var slidesShown = 0;
$('ul').jwSlider({
    speed : 2500,
    pause : 3000,
    slideShown: function(){
        slidesShown++;
        if (slidesShown == 6)
            window.location = "http://go.to/somewhere";
    }
});
```